12V to 5V buck converter - why did my IC fry?
I assembled a 12-to-5V buck converter from an LM64460-Q1 (datasheet) based on the design that Webench produced (design below).
I attempted to slowly (safely) ramp up input voltage with no load connected. A large current (~1A) began to be drawn until I was up at around operating voltage (12V) where current fell to ~6mA. Output voltage measured at only 1.5V. I noticed when disconnecting my bench supply the output voltage remained at 1.5V, so I briefly shorted the output terminals to discharge the output caps and try the process over again.
Except from this point onwards I had no output at all and no input current. I confirmed the SW terminal of the IC was now shorted to GND, so the chip is broken.
I replaced the IC and repeated the ramp up process but with a 100mA current limit on my bench supply. I could only reach 4V input voltage before the CC mode kicked in and can't get up to operating voltage. I don't want to fry it again, is something wrong with my design that would cause this?
Is there possibly some instability at lower voltage causing high power dissipation in the IC, and I need to avoid supplying low voltages? Is there a large startup current that's expected but which will be very brief if I step the input directly to 12V, that shouldn't damage anything?
EDIT
With the replaced chip, I increased the current limit on my bench supply to 0.5A and voltage set to 12V. Still with no load I applied power in a step fashion (rather than gradual ramp up). The output voltage remained pegged at 4V, consuming the full 0.5A. Output voltage measured 0.6V

(IC is mislabelled as LM63460, it's actually LM64460 and specifically the 5V fixed output variant)



Just a guess, but at sufficiently low input voltage, the high side switch (MOSFET) will not be fully on (even with bootstrap capacitor) resulting in heating of the switch. That might explain the first test burning up.

You said "I attempted to slowly (safely) ramp up input voltage with no load connected...".
This is very possibly the problem.
With a slow ramp, then the top switch will not get fully turned on, and the datasheet  has this to say:

8.3.8 Bootstrap Voltage and UVLO (CBOOT)
The gate driver of the high-side (HS) switch requires a bias voltage higher than >VIN. Th bootstrap capacitor, CBOOT, connected between CBOOT and SW, works as a
charge pump to boost the voltage on CBOOT to a level of VCC above the
SW voltage. The LM64460-Q1 has an integrated bootstrap diode to
minimize external component count. Use a 100-nF bootstrap capacitor
rated for 10 V or higher. The VBOOT-UVLO threshold (2.1V typical) is
designed to maintain proper HS switch operation. If the bootstrap
capacitor voltage drops below VBOOT-UVLO, then the converter initiates
a charging sequence, turning on the low-side switch before attempting
to turn on the HS switch.

My take is that this 'charging sequence' is happening a lot during the startup you describe which could very possibly destroy the bottom transistor. which would explain your short to ground from the switch node.
Normal startup is for the input to ramp within perhaps a few tens to hundreds of milliseconds.

If true this seems like a design vulnerability (of my design, not the LM64460 itself) since my supply will ultimately be a battery which could drop below 12V. I could rely on BMS overdischarge to protect the buck converter from this failure mode, but the IC has an undervoltage lockout feature using a resistor divider across the EN pin. Curious why Webench didn't design this in, given that I provided the range of voltages I wanted to operate over.

Provided you are well above 5V (I haven't got to the maximum duty cycle bit yet) it should be fine. As a test, you could set the undervoltage lockout at perhaps 6V and see what happens.


I assembled a 12-to-5V buck converter from an LM64460-Q1

Your schematic has something else but they seem to be pin-to-pin compatible. So I'm ignoring this for now.

Total input capacitance seems a bit small to me. I didn't check the entire datasheet but I'd place at least 10μ.
I'd also consider placing a dummy load to force a non-zero current flow through the switches and the inductor.

The problem wound up being assembly issues.
Despite the fact that I ohm'd the board and found no sign of any shorts, after desoldering and resoldering the IC a dozen times and realizing different (but undersired) behavior with each iteration, I finally achieved a normal 5V output.
In the end, the design is perfectly capable of being run from a supply with a low current limit (35mA) and slowly ramping Vin from 0V to the target input voltage (12V). The highest supply current I witnessed doing this on the final working iteration was 3mA.
